# How to make a python calculator with that can add , subtract , multiply , divide , powers and modulo on more more than two numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

i'm quite new at Python and I wondered how to make a calculator that i can add, subtract, multiply, divide and other operators on more than two numbers  . I would be thankful if you gave me an explanation. I'm questioning  because I have in my mind an awful and inefficient method of doing this , that being adding more elif tags for more operators and more numbers

TL:DR (i guess) :
i thinked about making a calculator made with python that has options for more operator and numbers ( but i don't know how to make a simpler one :
i.e.:30 + 30 * 30.
67.874 / 20.
69 + 69 + 69 + 69 + 69 + 69.
30 ** ( i think this is a power operator ) 2.
etc.
I can help you if you didin't understand what i want , you can question me

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site is not meant for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working, we can help you with that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and [ask]. SO is not meant for tutorials. Instead, we recommend you write it yourself, but ask a question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

this is my normal calculator without input of more than two numbers and one operator

```
def add(x, y):
return x + y


def subtract(x, y):
return x - y


def multiply(x, y):
return x * y


def divide(x, y):
return x / y


num1 = float(input("Enter a number :"))
op = input("Enter your selected operator :")
num2 = float(input("Enter another number :"))

if op == "+":
print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

elif op == "-":
print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

elif op == "*":
print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

elif op == "/":
print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))

else:
print("Invalid input")
```

I know this comment/answer code isn't having indenting , but stack woudn't let me post with indenting and the file itself does have indenting so idk

Answer (score 0):

```
result = None
operand = None
operator = None
wait_for_number = True

while True:
    if operator == '=':
        print(f"Result: {result}")
        break
    elif wait_for_number == True:
        while True:
            try:
                operand = float(input("Enter number: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("Oops! It is not a number. Try again.")
            else:
                if result == None:
                    result = operand
                else:
                    if operator == '+':
                        result = result + operand
                    elif operator == '-':
                        result = result - operand
                    elif operator == '*':
                        result = result * operand
                    elif operator == '/':
                        result = result / operand
                break
        wait_for_number = False
    else:
        while True:
            operator = input("Enter one of operators +, -, *, /, =: ")
            if operator in ('+', '-', '*', '/', '='):
                break
            else:
                print("Oops! It is not a valid operator. Try again.")
        wait_for_number = True
```

Answer (score -1):

your question isn’t clear enough, but if I got it right than this should work. Important to note: using the eval() function is not a good practice since it can be really dangerous if the inputs are not coming from you. Here are some of the dangers of it: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

The code:

```
# the function takes an operator as a string like: “*” and multiple numbers thanks to the * (args) operator.
def calculate(operator, *numbers):
    
    result = numbers[0]

    #the for cycle goes through all numbers except the first
    for number in range(1, len(numbers)):
        #the eval() function makes it possible to python to interpret strings as a code part
        result = eval(f"{result} {operator} {str(numbers[i])}")
    print(result)
```

Here is the code without eval().

```
import operator

# the function takes an operator as a string like: “*” and multiple numbers thanks to the * (args) operator.
def calculate(op, *numbers):

   # binding each operator to its string counterpart
   operators = {
       "+": operator.add,
       "-": operator.sub,
       "*": operator.mul,
       "/": operator.truediv
   }

   result = numbers[0]

   #the for cycle goes through all numbers except the first
   for number in range(1, len(numbers)):
       # carrying out the operation, using the dictionary above
       result = operators[op](result, numbers[number])
   print(result)
```

Comment: Where is that f...ing tutorial where they advocate the use of `eval`? If you can't explain in detail what `eval` does you shouldn't use it. Read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Wow, chill man. I didn't mean any harm. I know using eval() is a bad practice but the guy just wanted a basic calculator.

Comment: Big thanks man , but it dosen't want to run and i want to input numbers , but i can't seem to make to enter input

Comment: And i'm sorry that i can't respond right away , but the time zone is UTC+03:00

Comment: Hi, what error did you get? When I tried to call it, like this it worked fine for me:                       Input: `calculate(“*”, 2 , 5, 6) `                                   Output: `60 `